# Elastalert use field value as to address in email alert

Tags: email, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastalert

Currently, I am using elasticsearch to store the data, Kibana for the visualization and elastalert for raising the alerts.

here is the working rule for the email alert using the blacklist rule.

```
name: email blacklist rule

type: blacklist

index: subjects

compare_key: subject

blacklist:
- "Hindi"

alert:
- "email"

email:
 - "example@gmail.com"
```

This rule is working fine when I hardcoded the email address in the rule.

Here is the one of the docs of the elasticsearch index:

```
{
  "subject" : "Hindi",
  "@timestamp" : "2020-08-19T12:23:00.000Z",
  "mail_to" : "sample@gmail.com"
}
```

Now is there any way to pick the email from the doc and send email to it?

I mean instead of example@gmail.com the mail should be sent to sample@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending alerts to the mail which is present in one of the fields of the doc which is going through the elastalert rules we can use inbuilt feature call

```
email_from_field: "fields_that_consists_emailid"
```

here is one of the doc in the index:

```
{
  "subject" : "Hindi",
  "@timestamp" : "2020-08-19T12:23:00.000Z",
  "mail_to" : "sample@gmail.com"
}
```

here is the working rule for it:

```
name: field value rule

type: blacklist

index: subjects

compare_key: subject

blacklist:
- "Hindi"

alert:
- "email"

email:
 - "example@gmail.com"
 
email_from_field: "mail_to"
```

In the above mentioned rule the email is the required parameter which will be used in case there is no valid mail-id in the email_from_field parameter.

So, in the above mentioned rule the alert will be sent to the sample@gmail.com